# PHP - Get Values Inside Element Based on className HTML

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

```
<div class="ContentsList">
    <dl>
    <dt><img src="/user_data/packages/achievement/img/products/ttl_taofc.gif" alt="目次" width="76" height="17" /></dt>
    <dd>
     <ol>
      <li><em>東京都</em></li>
      <li class="Indent"><em>second</em><span>second data</span></li>
      <li class="Indent"><em>third</em><span>third data</span></li>
      <li class="Indent"><em>Fourth</em><span>fourth data</span></li>
      <li class="NoBorder"><em>no</em></li>
     </ol>
    </dd>
   </dl>
</div>
<div class="anotherList">
  <li><em>another</em><span>another data</span></li>
</div>
```

Assuming I have HTML content above and I am trying to get the all contents inside the class `ContentsList`.

Here is what I've tried

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><meta charset="UTF-8">' . $htmlContent);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
$classQueries = $finder->query('//div[@class="ContentsList"]');

foreach ($classQueries as $query) {
    var_dump($query->nodeValue);
}
```

The output result in string:

```
東京都
secondsecond data
thirdthird data
Fourthfourth data
no
```

The result is fine there is no space between the data in className `Indent`.
What if I want result should be:

```
東京都
second: second data
third: third data
Fourth: fourth data
no
```

Is it possible to loop through the `DomNodeList` and store the value in array format?

```
[ [
    '東京都'
  ],
  [
    'second' => 'second data'
  ],
  // and so on
]
```

Comment: Change the xpath expression so that you are looping directly over the `li`. Then in this instance here you can simply access their first and last child (there are special named properties for those; if it were other elements or a different structure, you would have to find them inside the element's children yourself) - https://3v4l.org/KE9G4